# How to make a tab menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I want when i click on `#tab1` then first `panel` with id `tab1` should be open. and that process done with all `li`.

I am not perfect in `jquery`.

Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('ul li a#').click(function(){
    $('').addClass('show')
  })
});
```

```css
ul{height: 40px;}
  li{float: left;padding: 5px;background-color: #ccc;color:#333;margin-left: 10px;list-style: none;}
  .panel{height:100px;width: 800px;margin: 0 auto 10px;background-color: #ccc;/*display: none;*/}
  .show{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel" id="tab1">
  1
</div>


<div class="panel" id="tab2">
  2
</div>


<div class="panel" id="tab3">
  3
</div>


<div class="panel">
  4
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide `#tab2`,  `#tab3` and `#tab4` when `#tab1` is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.show()` & `hide()` instead. Example:

```css
ul{height: 40px;}
    li{float: left;padding: 5px;background-color: #ccc;color:#333;margin-left: 10px;list-style: none;}
    .panel{height:100px;width: 800px;margin: 0 auto 10px;background-color: #ccc;/*display: none;*/}
    .show{display: block;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panel" id="tab1">
    1
</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab2">
    2
</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab3">
    3
</div>
<div class="panel"  id="tab4">
    4
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.panel').hide(); $('#tab1').show();
        $('ul li a').click(function(){
            $('.panel').hide();
            $(this).addClass('show');
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            $(id).show();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding class, you could simply use `.hide()` and `.show()` and add the `data-id` attribute to the `a` elements with corresponding `id`, so that when it is being click you could retrieve the `id` and apply `.show()` on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.panel').hide();
  $('#tab1').show();
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).show();
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  height: 40px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.panel {
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="tab3">Tab3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panel" id="tab1">1</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab2">2</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab3">3</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab4">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will propose pure CSS solution without any javascript at all. You can use [`:target`](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/) pseudo class to show panels which id corresponds to currently selected location hash.

To achieve this you need to set `.panel` hidden by default and show it with the rule `.panel:target {display: block}`.

```css
ul {height: 40px;}
li {float: left; padding: 5px; background-color: #ccc; color:#333; margin-left: 10px;list-style: none;}

.panel {height: 100px; background-color: #ccc; display: none;}
.panel:target {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel" id="tab1">1</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab2">2</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab3">3</div>
<div class="panel" id="tab4">4</div>
```

Comment: first tab needs to be shown @dfsq here is the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltajjyq8/) was about to post it as the answer but you already did

Comment: You are right about the first tab, thank you. You can still post your solution, it's a little different, why not.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful to you!

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('ul li a').click(function(){

    var active_id = $('div.panel.show').attr('id');
    var new_id = $(this).attr('href');

    if( active_id !== 'undefined' && '#'+active_id == new_id ) {
      $(new_id).removeClass('show');
    }
    else {
      $('div.panel').removeClass('show');
      $(new_id).addClass('show');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
ul{height: 40px;}
  li{float: left;padding: 5px;background-color: #ccc;color:#333;margin-left: 10px;list-style: none;}
  .panel{height:100px;width: 800px;margin: 0 auto 10px;background-color: #ccc;display: none;}
  .show{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel" id="tab1">
  1
</div>


<div class="panel" id="tab2">
  2
</div>


<div class="panel" id="tab3">
  3
</div>


<div class="panel"  id="tab4">
  4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/9ujLL39r/)

```
  $(document).ready(function ($) {
            var firstitem = $("#tabmenu li").first();
            firstitem.addClass("activeitem");
            showSelectedItem(firstitem.find("a").attr("data-href"));
            $('#tabmenu li').click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("activeitem");
                $('#tabmenu li').not(this).removeClass("activeitem")
                showSelectedItem($(this).find("a").attr("data-href"));
                //  $('').addClass('show')
            })
        });

        function showSelectedItem(selector) {
            $(selector).addClass("activepanel").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".panel").not(selector).removeClass("activepanel").hide();
        }
```

check this above example in the jsfidde, let me know your feedback